# AWK - if field in $6 contains "StringXY" then skip whole line and proceed

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, skip

```
if ($6 = "sum") {next};
```

Ok, that does not work. I need a way to skip a line if any field (here $6) contains the string "sum".
Important is here skip and not exit so awk continues parsing the following lines.

Comment: use `==` also, you can use `$6 != "suname" ...do some action`

Comment: You told us 3 different strings you want to find - `StringXY`, then `Summe`, then `sum`. Take an extra couple of seconds when posting to at the very least make your question consistent within itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($6 == "Summe") {next};
```

It should be `==` rather than `=`

Answer (score 1):

Or without the `if` depending:

```
awk '$6=="Summe"{next} ... '
```